# JOption call method from String text?

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I'm not too sure how to ask this question but here it is. Please look at my code (which I abbreviated for your convenience, and don't worry about the "Sam" its temporary)

```
public class JeopardyGUI_Main11 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form JeopardyGUI_Main
 */

public JeopardyGUI_Main11() {
    initComponents();
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
}
public void info(){
           String[] am = new String[25];
   String[] sp = new String[25];
   String[] mu = new String[25];
   String[] spe = new String[25];
   String[] tv = new String[25];
   String[] mo = new String[25];

   String[] ama = new String[25];
   String[] spa = new String[25];
   String[] mua = new String[25];
   String[] spea = new String[25];
   String[] tva = new String[25];
   String[] moa = new String[25];

   am[0] = "Sam";ama[0] = "Sam";
   am[1] = "Sam";ama[1] = "Sam";
   ...
   am[23] = "Sam";ama[23] = "Sam";
   am[24] = "Sam";ama[24] = "Sam";

   mu[0] = "Sam";mua[0] = "Sam";
   mu[1] = "Sam";mua[1] = "Sam";
   ...
   mu[23] = "Sam";mua[23] = "Sam";
   mu[24] = "Sam";mua[24] = "Sam";



   spe[0] = "Sam";spea[0] = "Sam";
   spe[1] = "Sam";spea[1] = "Sam";
   ...
   spe[23] = "Sam";spea[23] = "Sam";
   spe[24] = "Sam";spea[24] = "Sam";


   tv[0] = "Sam";tva[0] = "Sam";
   tv[1] = "Sam";tva[1] = "Sam";
  ...
   tv[23] = "Sam";tva[23] = "Sam";
   tv[24] = "Sam";tva[24] = "Sam";


   sp[0] = "Sam";spa[0] = "Sam";
   sp[1] = "Sam";spa[1] = "Sam";
  ...
   sp[23] = "Sam";spa[23] = "Sam";
   sp[24] = "Sam";spa[24] = "Sam";


   mo[0] = "Sam";moa[0] = "Sam";
   mo[1] = "Sam";moa[1] = "Sam";
   ...
   mo[23] = "Sam";moa[23] = "Sam";
   mo[24] = "Sam";moa[24] = "Sam";

    int random_int = (int) (Math.random() * ( 0 - 24 ));  

  String am_qu = am[random_int];
  String am_an = ama[random_int];  

  String sp_qu = sp[random_int];
  String sp_an = spa[random_int];

  String mu_qu = mu[random_int];
  String mu_an = mua[random_int];

  String spe_qu = sp[random_int];
  String spe_an = spa[random_int];

  String tv_qu = tv[random_int];
  String tv_an = tva[random_int];

  String mo_qu = mo[random_int];
  String mo_an = moa[random_int];
  }

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void sp1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                                     


private void sp2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

private void am1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Object[] options = {"Yes, please",
                "No way!"};
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
""+am_qu,          <-------------------------------------AREA IN QUESTION
"",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
null,     //do not use a custom Icon
options,  //the titles of buttons
options[0]); //default button title



}                                   

private void mo1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

private void am1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JeopardyGUI_Main11.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JeopardyGUI_Main11.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JeopardyGUI_Main11.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JeopardyGUI_Main11.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JeopardyGUI_Main11().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton am1;
private javax.swing.JButton am2;
private javax.swing.JButton am3;
...
private javax.swing.JButton am4;
private javax.swing.JButton am5;

// End of variables declaration                   


}
```

At the "AREA IN QUESTION" I put is the location of the problem. The optionDialog box needs a String for the text, but i want to replace it with the String from the "public void info()" which will be randomized with the Math.Random.

So, the optionDialog should read "Sam" (in the middle text area) if I were to run it properly.

I'm sorry if I did not make this clear enough, ask anything, i'll be waiting for a response, thanks!

Comment: At the end of your info method you have 12 random Strings, are you saying you want one of those Strings to be the message in your JOPtionPane?

Comment: Yes, they are the randomizers, and I want the result to appear withing the ("") of the JOptionPane making it the "body text".

Comment: Yes, but do you want 1 of those 12 Strings at random, or all of them to appear within the ("")?

Comment: Yes one of them, because I will assign different buttons with the other random strings. Basically to randomize the jeopardy questions per button. 6 columns of different topics, with 5 button choices each, the buttons will be displaying one of the random questions (that i will input in place of "Sam") and then ill allow the user to input an answer and compare it to the answer Strings. Thanks for your time!

Comment: The main problem here is variable scope.  Regardless of how many times you call the method to initialize those variables, they'll only live until the end of the method.  Consider moving where they live to a field.

Comment: What do you mean by field? I tried movie the array and its properties to other places but it results in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a different way you could structure your program which may be more efficient:

```
public class SO {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    getinfo();//Set the random question and answer

    Object[] options = {"Yes, please", "No way!"};
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            SO.question,//Reference the question set
            "",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,     //do not use a custom Icon
            options,  //the titles of buttons
            options[0]); //default button title

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, SO.answer);
}

public static void getinfo(){ //Will set question and answer
    int category = new Random().nextInt(2 - 0);//Random number to get a category
    int choice = new Random().nextInt(2 - 0);//Random to get a selection

    SO.question = questions[category][choice];//Get question
    SO.answer = answers[category][choice];//Answer is located in same position in answers array
}

/*Each category is represented by a seperate array within the questions
 * 2 dimensional array.  These are declared as static fields or 'Global fields'
 * This way they are easily accessible and only initialised once
 */
private static String[][] questions = new String[][]{ 
    {"Question 1, category 1", "Question 2 category 1"},//questions[0][*] for one category 
    {"Question 1 category 2", "Question 2 category 2"}//questions[1][*] on another category
};

/*The answers array mirrors the other array so each answer in this 2D array 
 * is in the same position as the relevant question in the questions array
 * 
 */
private static String[][] answers = new String[][]{ 
    {"Answer 1 category 1", "Answer 2 category 1"}, //answers[0][*] for questions [0][*]  
    {"Answer 1 category 2", "Answer 2 category 2"}//answers[1][*] for questions [1][*]
};

//These will each hold a question and an answer
private static String question;
private static String answer;
```

}

I have made it a lot smaller so you can get a feel for how it's working.  The 'Global variable' that have been suggested to you are at the bottom.  This should hopefully allow you to get your question and answer that you require for the JOPtionPane and prevent the continual re-initialisation of your arrays.

Once again, if unsure comment me back and I'll see what I can do.
Good Luck!

Comment: You are really close to answering me (with such detail too!) but here is what my goal is, the `String am`  is a category holding questions regarding (am)erica and the `String ama` has the answers to the questions all in order (am)erica (a)nswer. The entire program is supposed to be a Jeopardy game with different categories and corresponding answers.

Comment: @Magiichalo I have re-jigged my answer to demonstrate a way you could achieve what I think you are after, have a look and see if it helps

Comment: I tried it in a blank class and it works, now to fix it into my existing code. Thanks a million you genius!

Comment: one more thing, it does not allow me to add extra questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your program but I assume you're trying to instantiate a few String in the info() method and then use the value of those String in the am1ActionPerformed() method. Now, I don't understand your problem very well either but the what I see in your code is a problem of scope.

The String am_qu you're trying to access in the am1ActionPerformed() method does not exist because it is created and destroyed in the info() method. If you want to use it in another method, try making it a global variable instead.

---

update

The reason why it can't find the symbol is because it doesn't exist because of the scope. I don't know what you mean with the "I added Global instead of void info()" but the way you make a variable global is declaring it inside the class but outside everything else;

consider the following:

```
public class TempClass{
    public String globVar;       //global variable
    public void method1(){
        globVar ="hello";        // Same global variable
    }
    public void method2(){
        globVar ="world!";        // same here too
    }
}
```

Here the same variable globVar is accessible by both method1() and method2() and can be modified by both. calling method2() after method1 will replace the value of globVar
Consider  now a local variable.

```
public class TempClass{

    public void method1(){
        String localVar;       //local variable is declared
        localVar = "Hello";    //value assigned to local Variable
    }                          //localVar is destroyed

    public void method2(){
        String localVar;       // different localVar to method1
        localVar = "world";    // value assigned to localVar
    }                          // localVar destroyed
}
```

Here two different variables are used even though they are called the same. Not only that but they are destroyed when the method exits and cannot be used anywhere else.
Finally consider what you are doing so far

```
public class TempClass{

    public void method1(){
        String localVar;           //local variable is declared
        localVar = "Hello World";  //value assigned to local Variable
    }                              //localVar is destroyed

    public void method2(){
        System.out.println(localVar);  // Error. localVar does not exist
    }                                  
}
```

So as you can see you variable is destroyed before you can use it. You need to declare it globally.

Comment: I added `Global` instead of `void info()` which was ok but now the `am[0] = "Sam";ama[0] = "Sam";` are all giving errors cannot find symbol.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your option. I appreciate it.